# Website content alignment in ie8

Tags: html

I am facing website content(videos, images, texts) alignment problem in internet explorer 8, but its works fine in internet explorer 9. i have tried following code but its still same.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

Thanks

***Found the solution: - works fine for me***

**Was**

```
   <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" ">
```

**Now**

```
   <body>
```

Comment: Your meta tag let IE emulate IE7, you will emulate the edge (latest) version. Use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `EmulateIE7`, you should use `edge`. This will actually disable Compatibility Mode completely (except for when accessed with the Developer Tools), and this usually fixes most problems.

For anything more specific, a more specific question is needed.